# display an error message on a jsp using controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp

hi i have to display an error message on a jsp using a controller

this is the code of the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUrl(WebRequest request) {

    logger.info("Calling Add Filters in POST mode");

    String serverUrl = request.getParameter("serverUrl");
    logger.info("ServerUrl" + serverUrl);

    if(serverUrl!=null)
    {
        mongoService.setServerUrl(serverUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        //show message on UI if serverUrl is null

    }

    return "redirect:config.do";
}
```

sorry to say but i am completely new to spring so dont know to do it??.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the object of `ModelMap` ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUrl(WebRequest request,ModelMap map) {

    logger.info("Calling Add Filters in POST mode");

    String serverUrl = request.getParameter("serverUrl");
    logger.info("ServerUrl" + serverUrl);    
    if(serverUrl!=null)
    {
        mongoService.setServerUrl(serverUrl);
    }
    else
    {
       String errormsg="sorry un expected error has occured"
       map.put("errMsg",errormsg)
    }    
    return "redirect:config.do";
}
```

Can also be done using ,

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errMsg",errormsg);
```

`redirectAttributes.addAttribute` constructs request parameters out of your attributes and redirects to the desired page with the request parameters

And in your jsp ,

Can be accessed using EL   `${errMsg}`

Comment: <c:if test="${empty serverUrl}">
 <div ><c:out value="${errMsg}"/></div>
 </c:if>   //serverUrl is the id of the input box it should work right? but its not working .

Comment: Did you get any error ? _its not working_ is not a valid statement here

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectAttributes for this as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/failure")
    public ModelAndView loginFailure(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        String message = "Invalid username or password!";
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", message);
        // model.addObject("error",message);
        model.setViewName("redirect:/login");
        return model;
    }
```

and in the view you can simply display it as below:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><c:out value="${error}"/></div>
</c:if>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

it shows error on redirectAttributes 
i want to show error message on my login Screen when user inser Wrong password

my code is given Below;-

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value= "name") String name, @RequestParam(value= "password") String password,ModelMap m) throws SQLException{

    String uname= name;
    String pass= password; 


    Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sbank","root","root");
    Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery("select * from account where name='"+uname+"' and password='"+password+"'");

    if(resultSet.next()){

        return new ModelAndView("home","command",resultSet);

    }
    else{

        String message="Sorry UserName Or Password Is Wrong";   
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView();
         redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", message);
         model.setViewName("redirect:/Index.jsp");
            return model;
    }
}
```